# vainfo - iHD_drv_video.so init failed

Tags: intel-media-sdk

I'm trying to install MediaSDK in LattePanda board(Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel_version=4.14.16-041416-generic).
Lattepanda has Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350.

To install MediaSDK, I followed [this guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/build-and-debug-open-source-media-stack).

According to the referred guide one has to clone [MediaSDK repository](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK.git) from GitHub, but that repo does not include `tools/builder/build_mfx.pl` which I obtained from [another repo](https://github.com/projectceladon/MediaSDK).

When I run vainfo command after proceeding to step #10 it shows that iHD_drv_video.so init failed:

```
admin@lattepanda:~/work$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_5
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

[vainfo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDa3L.jpg)

Also, I set the relevant environment variables:

```
export export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD
export LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
```

Please help me. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to upgrade libva
2. Your intel gpu is not support by `LIBVA_DRIVER`.

Comment: To strengthen the second point, this CPU is probably for i965 driver, not iHD.